# How to sort based on sub table mysql and sequelize

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

I have a problem as follows:

I have 2 table

```
model Product {
 id      
 name    
 skus[]   Sku
}

model Sku {
 id
 name
 price
 weight
 productId
 product  Product
}
```

Data example:

- Product table

```
id    |    name
--------------------
1     |    product 1
2     |    product 2
3     |    product 3
```

- Sku table

```
id   |  name   | price  | weight | product_id  
--------------------------------------------------
1    | sku 1   |  10    |  2     |   1
2    | sku 2   |  12    |  1     |   1
3    | sku 3   |  11    |  3     |   1
4    | sku 4   |  12    |  3     |   2
5    | sku 5   |  15    |  1     |   2
```

=>> result expected:

- sort desc product by price of sku

```
id  | name  
---------
2   | product 2
1   | product 1
```

Now I want to get all products out as sorted by their price take lowest price of a SKU variation if a product contains more than 1 product variant.

Note: use sequelize

Comment: Can we see some sample data and the expected result please? I suggest you read these: [Provide a `Minimal Complete Verifiable Example` (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
and [Why should I provide a MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I just edit and add data example